# Subview auto layout constraint prevents resizing parent

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, autolayout, nsview

I have a simple subview inside a parent view positioned 60pts from the top and want to animate the parent view's height to zero on the click of a button. (i.e. **final parent size < top offset subview**)

```
 _______________  _                  ______________  _
|               |  |                |______________| _| 0pt
|    parent     |  | 60pt
| _____________ | _|       onClick
||             ||             ->   
||     sub     ||
||_____________||
 ---------------
```

Unfortunately the subview creates the following auto layout constraint:

```
superview.height = self.maxY + 60
```

Which means that if I animate the parent size like this:

```
parentView.animator().frame = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: NSSize(width: parentView.frame.width, height: 0))
```

The parent's height will be 60 instead of 0.
I actually **don't want to use auto layout** for this part of the app and simply set the `autoresizingMask`s of both views to `[.ViewWidthSizable, .ViewHeightSizable]`.
But since I use auto layout in some other section, apparently auto layout is enabled everywhere...

If I completely remove all auto layout views, than the animation works perfectly fine.

In short: **how to animate a parent view to be smaller than the top offset of its subview?**

If there is no other way than to use auto layout for the parent - subview relation, how to animate the parent to 0 height in that case?

Comment: You can create an IBOutlet of the height constraint and then you can change the value of that constraint to zero and the animation will work

Comment: Ah, forgot to tell that the views are created programmatically. So there is no way to do this without creating auto layout constraints myself?